# Deselected selected marker/vector in OpenLayers

Tags: java, openlayers, vaadin

I can't figure out how to deselect a selected vector (pointvector or other vectors) in Vaadin's OpenLayer-wrapper.

To enable selection of vectors, you use this method:

```
VectorLayer pointLayer = new VectorLayer();
pointLayer.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SIMPLE);
```

and to listen for vector onclick events, you use the following method:

```
pointLayer.addListener(new VectorSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void vectorSelected(VectorSelectedEvent event) {
        //do work
    }
});
```

and to get the currently selected vector yoy use this method:

```
Vector selectedVector = pointLayer.getSelectedVector();
```

But how can I deselect the selected vector when clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doing it by pressing a button. For example:

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    if (selectedVector != null) {
      VectorLayer vl = (VectorLayer) selectedVector.getParent();
      vl.setSelectedVector(null);
    }
});
```